# If $2 \tan B + \cot B = \tan A$, prove that $2 \tan (A-B) = \cot B$.

Tags: trigonometry

If $2 \tan B + \cot B = \tan A$, prove that $2 \tan (A-B) = \cot B$.
I am wondering how can i prove this question.
If any one has answer of it then it would be a great pleasure.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate $\tan(a-b)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:
$$\begin{align}2 \tan (A-B) &= \frac{2\tan A-2\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}=\\
&=\frac{2(2\tan B+\cot B)-2\tan B}{1+(2\tan B+\cot B)\tan B}=\\
&=\frac{2(\tan B+\cot B)}{1+(2\tan B+\cot B)\frac1{\cot B}}=\\
&=\frac{2(\tan B+\cot B)\cot B}{2(\tan B+\cot B)}=\\
&=\cot B\end{align}$$